# Web Service Proxy generates a base node, how to get rid of it

Tags: web-services, abap

I created a basic web service in C# .Net where I have a parent object with 4 levels of inheritance. (example child0 inherits from parent and child1 inherits from child0 etc.)

The parent only exposes a getMessage funcion and each object has a string variable. The function takes a string and returns a string with some characters appended. This was done as a test to try and figure out why the web service proxy in the ABAP world adds the base nodes.

I want to remove the base so that the structure isn't as complicated but it seems once you inherit from another object this is what you will see in SAP. Can one get rid of the base node?

See the screenshot below: [image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: i think the problem is your description, how did you create the proxy? did you use an WSDL? the method is generated automatically right isnt it? if so, your description has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the definition of your getMessageResult wsdl/XSD. The message type you have defined there is what causes the inheritance of those sub structures.